# Postgresql | remove all arrays that contains by others

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgresql-14

Let's for example I have the next table:

```
CREATE TABLE temp
(
    id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    arr bigint[] NOT NULL
);
```

And insert rows it:

```
INSERT INTO temp (arr) VALUES
(ARRAY[2, 3]),
(ARRAY[2,3,4]),
(ARRAY[4]),
(ARRAY[1, 2, 3])
```

So, I have now in the table:

[image]

I want to have a query that return only arrays which are unique (in a manner that are not contains by other arrays)
So, the return will be rows number 2 & 4 (the arr column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be don using a NOT EXISTS condition:

```
select t1.*
from temp t1
where not exists (select * 
                  from temp t2
                  where t1.id <> t2.id
                  and t2.arr @> t1.arr);
```

Comment: seems works, what is it `<>` and `@>` means?

Comment: `<>` is the operator for "not equal" in SQL. And the `@>` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) tests if one array is contained in another

Comment: is it possible to do it without any ids? i.e. having only column of arrays? (a result from a `group by` statement)